# Specify the number of simultaneous times an API call takes place

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following object:

```
addresses: [
    {
        address: "1234 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "4444 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "5555 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "6666 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "7777 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    }
]
```

The real one has about 1,500 records.

This array is loaded on an angular application and displayed on a table.

For each address at this array, an API is called (on my end), where the address is verified.

The problem I have is I was asked to place a "VERIFY ALL" button, and when running the above array through a loop, it all works fine when calling the API 45-50 times, the rest of the calls just won't respond.

```
for (let address of addresses) {
    //here Im calling the API for each address, and getting a "True" or "False" response
}
```

Is it possible to run the API call (from Angular) in batches of 10 addresses, and move to the next 10 ones after those provided already a response?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just loop through in an inner and outer loop. The inner loop should create 10 promises. The outer loop should resolve them, like with Promises.all() or Promises.allsettled(). Then the inner loop should make the next ten promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate them into batches like so:

```js
  results: boolean[] = [];

  async ngOnInit() {
    const batchSize = 3;
    const numBatches = Math.ceil(addresses.length / batchSize);
    for (let batch = 0; batch < numBatches; batch++) {
      const promises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
        const index = batch * batchSize + i;
        if (index >= addresses.length) break;
        const promise = firstValueFrom(this.api.callApi(addresses[index]));
        promises.push(promise);
      }
      const batchResults = await Promise.all(promises);
      for (const result of batchResults) this.results.push(result);
      // Optional sleep between batches
      const sleep = 5000;
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(null), sleep));
    }
    console.log(this.results);
  }
```

Here's an example calling the jokes api, waiting 5 seconds between so you can see each batch come in:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvrimb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Keep in mind that api has a limit of 120 requests every 60 seconds so you'll get errors if you refresh too fast.

Comment: @Danielle I rewrote this since I made an error the first time. You can't create the promises for a batch until the previous batch completes.